# Microsoft Access 2007 accdr extension an Vista 64 bit OS

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, runtime, ms-access-2007

Has anyone ever tested a Microsoft Access 2007 .accdr application on Windows Vista 64 bit version? I sell a shareware program using the Access 2007 runtime, and, for one customer with that setup, there's some kind of problem. According the user ".  When I try to execute the program, it opens IE and then brings up the dialog box to either Open, Save, or Cancel the "myprogram.accdr" file.  If I choose run it simply goes away and then returns back to the same question"

It sound like this somehow got mapped to IE. On my windows XP system, it starts Access and runs the program. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the file associations for the accdr extension?

Answer (score 1):

MS Access isn't supported on 64bit, as it requires a 64bit JET engine which isn't available, Microsoft only released a 32bit JET engine. So your application has to run on WOW so it runs as 32bit and therefore is able to use the 32bit jet engine.

Comment: Your answer is contradictory. Access runs on 64-bit Windows via the 32-bit subsystem, just as 16-bit Access 2 ran on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: sure, it does through the 32bit subsystem (WOW) but you explicity have to run it on the 32bit subsystem, also your own apps. If you don't do that, you'll run into the problem as I described.

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine. After 3 weeks of hair pulling with access installer packager. I got it wot work. your references must be added in the packager or you will get run time errors. Billions of them.. Not really 4 or 5. and then it will not recognize the built in functions like date, time, isloaded....etc.

SO YES IT WILL WORK.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding as many references as possible by utilizing late binding. I never distribute any apps with anything but the default 3 Access references, Access, VBA and DAO.

Answer (score -1):

Is the customer using the 64 bit IE? Access 2007 is 32 bit only. The 32 bit IE might work properly.

Comment: How does IE come into play? Is it the "file explorer" or the "web browser". How do I get the customer to use the 32 bit ie?

Comment: Oh, I see. He launches it and *then* IE runs. Hmmm, there is a 32 and 64 bit Explorer as well. 64 bit in System32, 32 bit in SysWow64 (I think, I have a 64 bit machine at work, can't check here). I think there are seperate icons in the start menu too, but not certain.